# How can I initialize a classic register in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, arithmetic

is there a way to initialize a classic register in qiskit? I will go quickly through my problem and then suggest one solution but I am not satisfied with that and ask if there is another solution.

Basically, I want to implement this circuit.
[image]

Now, y is classically known therefore there is actually no need to use a QuantumRegister. Now I want to implement this in Qiskit but therefore I need to know if there is a way to initialize a classical register. For example, if y is '101' I want the classical bit '0' and '2' to be 1 and the cbit '1' to be 0.

One way I can think of is using a separated QuantumRegister and Initialize the according qubits with 1 and then measure and save it in the Classical Register. But I am not satisfied with this solution because this will require more qubits.

As I'm writing this there might be another way by reusing the second QuantumRegister(the blank spots between y and x) where I could first initialize a y and then measure (save it to the classical register) it and reset it to |0>. But this seems like a workaround and not a straightforward solution.

EDIT: Another, possible solution is to just ignore the gates if the y' bit is zero and don't add them to the circuit in the first place because we know how y looks in binary, we just need to consider it in the circuit.
But as I mentioned before this sounds like a workaround again. (But this time with some benefits for the absolute circuit depth :))

For everyone interested the circuit basically turns |x> into -|x> if x is greater or equal to a y. This is possible by computing the carry bits of y' + x, where y' = 2^(n+m) - y, with n+m is the amount of qubits you need to display x.
Here is the link to the paper if someone is interested in further reading. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.06159.pdf)